# ¿Las propiedades de la interfaces son estáticas?¿Se puede evitar de alguna forma? C#

Tags: c#, interface

Tengo dos clases diferentes que implementan una interfaz. La interfaz solo tiene una referencia a una estructura. Muy resumido viene a ser algo como lo que sigue.

```
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public struct SData
{
    public int dato; 
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public interface Interface
{
    public SData Data { set; get; }
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class Base1 : Interface
{
    public SData Data { set; get; }
    public SData sData;

    public void Start()
    {
        sData = new SData();
        sData.dato = 10;
        Data = sData;
    }  
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class Base2 : Interface
{
    public SData Data { set; get; }
    public SData sData;

    public void Start()
    {
        sData = new SData();
        sData.dato = 50;
        Data = sData;
    }  
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------

Luego tengo varias clases que son derivadas de estas dos ultimas. Pero en este caso concreto el problema se da entre dos clases derivadas de la clase Base1 (por ejemplo).

Estoy usando esta función que sirve para detectar colisiones en Unity. Cuando dos objetos colisionan se puede obtener información del otro objeto de la forma siguiente.

//--------------------------------------------------

```
public virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
        if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Interface info))
        {
            Debug.Log(" dato-->" + info.dato);
        }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------

Lo raro de todo esto es que si esos dos objetos son clases derivadas de la clase Base1 ¿como es posible que el valor de info.dato=50?... Lo único que se me ocurre es que ese campo sea estático o algo asi...

**¿Se puede impedir de alguna forma que pase esto? Y sin no... ¿Alguna otra alternativa para hacer lo mismo?**

Tengo como tres biblias y medio Don Quijote de scripts basandome en esa intefaz y esto me ha roto todos los esquemas. Cualquier ayuda para solucionar este problema será eternamente agradecida.

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
¿Podria ser este el problema?
Estoy declarando una interfaz como miembro de una clase... ¿es esto estático?
Estoy haciendo algo asi..

```
    public MyClass
    {
         public Interface _interface;
    
         public MyClass(Interface _interface)
         {
              this._interface =  _interface;
         }    
    }


MyClass b1 = new MyClass(Base1);
MyClass b2 = new MyClass(Base2);
```

El editor me dice que se se están usando las variables en el mismo sitio pero no se si se están sobreescribiendo y eso estaría causando el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El interfaz no es estatico ni dinamico. Simplemente crea una obligatoriedad de que las clases que implementen ese interfaz deban cumplir ciertas normas, en tu caso que todas tengan una propiedad Data de tipo SData. El problema que tienes no es por la interfaz..deberías depurar el código para ver donde se está poniendo ese valor a 50

Comment: Tampoco termino de entender para que almacenas la instancia de tus clases en `MyClass`, aunque supongo que `MyClass` tendra algo mas que desconocemos

Comment: Si, la uso para enviar datos en eventos  MyClass=EventInfo Y SData los datos que se envian... pero necesito que este en una interfaz para que sea abstracto y poder obtener y/o enviar esos datos de diversas formas (en collisiones or ejemplo) --> public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent; ... En eso estoy... intentado hacer una traza a ver si averiguo que está pasando...Si ninguna de esas cosas es estatica el tema se vuelve mas enigmatico aun...ya no se me ocurre que puede ser :-(

Comment: A no ser que unity haga algo extraño que podría ser (no he usado nunca unity), no, no parece haber nada estatico ahi

Comment: Ok, por lo menos ya tengo algo para ir descartando...todavia no controlo muy bien el funcionamiento de la intefaces y por eso tengo este tipo de dudas... Muchas Gracias Pikoh!!

Comment: Que  las clases Base1 y Base2 sean derivadas de otra clase abstracta y sobreescriban las mismas funciones podría ser motivo de este comportamiento?

Comment: Eso si podria ser

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Conseguí averigüar lo que era... tenia varios scripts en ese mismo objeto que implementaban esa misma interfaz... y la función de Unity pilla el primero que encuntre y se queda tan fresca... asi que por el momento lo he solucionado poniendo el que me interesa el primero de la lista hasta que se me ocurra otra cosa... bufff... menos mal... me estaba volviendo loco XD... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Pikoh!! Saludos!!